# Atlas print-out to one-page pdf

Tags: qgis, atlas, geospatial-pdf

I have a layer with 135 polygons and i have created an atlas that printout all 135 polygons in one PDF with 135 pages and I can also print out 135 PDF if I use the "Export to PDF" button and every PDF is named after the data in the polygon if I use the export-button 135 times ([next object, export, save, save] x 135)

But can I do an "Export to PDF" that creates 135 one-paged PDFs with the correct names in one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the `Atlas` tab of the print layout you need to uncheck the `Single file export when possible` box. This will then allow you to edit the `Output filename expression` to set the names of your pdfs.

Comment: When I unchecked "Single file ..." and press export I still just got the polygon that is showing in the printout-window. When I pressed the print-button I still got one (1) pdf with 135 pages.  I want 135 pdfs instead with one (1) page. Maybe I misunderstood how you meant ?

Comment: Are you using the `export` button to the right of the atlas controls? there is a drop down to select pdf if that is not showing.

Comment: NO I thought the two "export to pdf" was the same, thanks a lot.

The export-function isn’t working properly. I would guess that the problem is the ":" in the name 

When using the left "export to pdf" Qgis is correctly naming the files and replacing : with _ so "Kalmare 1:40" is called "Kalmare 1_40.pdf" 

but the right "export to pdf" is creating a file that is called "Kalmare 1" with no size